# How can I access lighter or darker shades of my Material-UI palette?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

As per [documentation](https://material-ui.com/customization/color/), I have created a Material-UI palette with different hue's and shades of blue and red. I would like to be able to access these different shades when I create components.

For example, when I create a button, `<Button variant="contained" color="primary">click</Button>`, is there a way to tell Material-UI to use the light version of the primary color?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass the *hue* directly to the *style* property:

```
import red from "@material-ui/core/colors/red";

const primaryLight = red["A100"];

...

<Button variant="contained" style={{ backgroundColor: primaryLight }}>click</Button>
```

Or if you want to create a [*theme*](https://material-ui.com/customization/palette/#example):

**index.js**

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { createMuiTheme } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import { ThemeProvider } from "@material-ui/styles";
import red from "@material-ui/core/colors/red";
import MyComponent from "./MyComponent";

const primary = red[500];
const primaryLight = red["A100"];

const theme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      light: primaryLight,
      main: primary
    }
  }
});

function App() {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <div className="App">
        <MyComponent />
      </div>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}
```

**Mycomponent.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { useTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';

function MyComponent() {
  const theme = useTheme();
  const primaryLight = theme.palette.primary.light;

  const styles = {
    button: {
      backgroundColor: primaryLight,
    },
  }

  return (
    <Button variant="contained" style={styles.button}>click</Button>
  )
}

export default MyComponent;
```

**Demo:**

[image: Edit Material-ui hues and theme]

Answer (score 0):

You could try modifying the theme object which you are supplying to your ThemeProvider depending on your and/or the user's choice by modifying the `type` attribute in your palette. Then i would suggest to provide different ThemeProviders for the parts that you want light or dark:

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    type: 'dark', // or light
    // ... your colors & shades of dark/light
  },
});
```

[To the documentation](https://material-ui.com/customization/palette/#type-light-dark-theme)